# Implementing confirm() with Jquery Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, sweetalert

I want to implement a `confirm()` on JavaScript with the famous sweet alert plugins. but somehow sweet alert doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
function kendaraan(param) {
        if (swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You wanna leave this page?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, Leave!",
                closeOnConfirm: false
              },
                function(){

                })
            ){
            switch (param) {
                case "ADD_KENDARAAN" :
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "pages/lj_menu/vehicle/add_vehicle.php",
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#lj-mainpage').html(response);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

So my intention when user click "ADD KENDARAAN", it should show sweet alert confirmation and when user click yes then execute the ajax portion.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `if` since its unnecessary. According to docs just implement your `switch` inside `anonymous function` for `success` as below:

```
function kendaraan(param) {
     swal({   
           title: "Are you sure?",
           text: "You wanna leave this page?",
           type: "warning",
           showCancelButton: true,
           confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
           confirmButtonText: "Yes, Leave!",
           closeOnConfirm: false
     },
     function(){   
           switch (param) {
                case "ADD_KENDARAAN" :
                      $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "pages/lj_menu/vehicle/add_vehicle.php",
                            success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) 
                                     {
                                        $('#lj-mainpage').html(response); 
                                        swal("Deleted!", "Your imaginary file has been deleted.", "success"); });
                                        //keep success message here if you wish to
                             }
                      });
                  break;
            }
     });
}
```

<kbd>**[`From the DOCS`](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/)**</kbd>